# Alfresco: Which tables do I need to query to get workflow details

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

I am trying to generate analytics reports using high charts.

For that I need to get values from alfresco DB using Postgres query. Can any one tell me what are the tables related workflow creation and save all workflow details.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the raw database tables? Why not take the easy route and ask the `WorkflowService` and friends in Java for the details?

Comment: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/resources/org/activiti/db/create/activiti.postgres.create.engine.sql

Answer (score 2):

I got some references from the below link.
http://techogeek.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-retrieve-activiti-workflow-details.html

As Gagravarr suggests, don't hit the database directly and use always the workflowservice to get the data workflow related data.

**ACT_RE_***: RE stands for repository. Tables with this prefix contain static information such as process definitions and process resources (images, rules, etc.).

**ACT_RU_***: RU stands for runtime. These are the runtime tables that contain the runtime data of process instances, user tasks, variables, jobs, etc. Activiti only stores the runtime data during process instance execution, and removes the records when a process instance ends. This keeps the runtime tables small and fast.

**ACT_ID_*:** ID stands for identity. These tables contain identity information, such as users, groups, etc.

**ACT_HI_*:** HI stands for history. These are the tables that contain historic data, such as past process instances, variables, tasks, etc.

**ACT_GE_*:** general data, which is used in various use cases.